# Can the native email client serve as a share target?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, share, email

Does Windows 8's built-in email client serve as a share target and, if so, will it send email sent it in this fashion (shared with it programmatically) without requiring direct user intervention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I can decrypt your question.

**Yes**: the email client pre-installed on Windows 8 (the "native" one) is a share target, yes. It is a PlainText and HtmlText share target out-of-the-box. All you need to do is share out from your app and Mail comes up as a potential target in the list.

As a result, the entire mail operation is handled by the mail application. You can't automate it. You also can't interrupt it. Once you share out, the target app handles the payload as it pleases.

If you want to automate an email send operation you need a service to help you do it. If you want to handle it on the client, read this: http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/windows8-metro-app-winrt-send-email-emailcomposetask.aspx

**Note**: You should note that the operating system brokers all interaction across the share operation. This means you cannot reach out to the share target from your app, and the share target cannot reach back to your application. The best you have is knowledge of which target app the user has selected.

- Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.targetapplicationchosen

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a share target, and no you can't use it to send mail without user intervention - that's not how the share target is designed to work.